# Integration library structure

Tags: c#, design-patterns, structure

My company have a library of integrations with a generic "front". One of our products is a simple web booking working and with our integration library we can add appointments in several external systems - from Microsoft Exchange and Google Calendar to appointment registers in EMR systems. We have a total of 28 integrations in this library.

This is a simplified example of how some of the time requests are handled for integrations to SystemA and SystemB.

[image]

The parameters to `GetTimes` are actually bundled in a `GetTimesParameters` object, but presented here as separate input parameters.

To use the integration library we have a simple factory method returning an `ImplementationBase` object and an extension library to convert the ImplementationBase object to different interfaces:

```
// Create ImplementationBase object
var implementation = ImplementationFactory.Create(ImplementationEnum.SystemA);

// Set implementation connection data
implementation.SetConnection("...");

// Get an ITime object
var timeImplementation = implementation.AsTime();

// Get the times from today and two days forward
var times = timeImplementation.GetTimes(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(2));
```

The `AsTime()` extension method throws a specific exception if the interface is not implemented by the implementation.

This has been working good enough, but it's getting a bit hard to maintain.

Simple validation is one thing. In the `GetTimes` call we check if the `from` DateTime is before the `to` DateTime - this is made by all `GetTime` implementations.

Another problem is how not implemented methods are handled. The `GetTimes` and `GetTimeTypes` methods are almost always used together. But in one integration there are no time types. The method `GetTimeTypes()` throws a `ImplementationMethodNotSupportedException()` and the `timeTypeId` parameter in `GetTimes` is ignored.

I'm sure there are other problems, but these two came to mind just right now and the validation problem is causing the most headaches.

I want a new layer on top of this. Where common validation can be handled and perhaps where the application can override behaviors - like handle an `ImplementationMethodNotSupportedException` in the `GetTimeTypes` example as returning an empty list of time types.

But I'm not sure how to do it. Any suggestions to improve our approach or a complete remodel would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding validation in GetTimes methods.

You said that You have GetTimesParameters class which is passed to GetTimes methods. Then it should not be possible to create invalid instance of GetTimesParameters. Just do validation in it's constructor and GetTimes methods don't need to validate incoming parameter.

Comment: We don't want the parameter classes to have constructors, but we could add a Validate method to it and call that method in each implementation.

Comment: Why not? Constructors exist for a reason. Since .NET allows initializer syntax more and more programmers forget about constructors. And these classes do contain constructor, its just that You don't make it work for You. If you add Validate method you still have to remember to call it in any of 28 implementation classes - DRY.